# Filter DataFrame based on total number of seconds in a timedelta column

Tags: python, pandas

My df  looks like this.

```
      date            pre_date              time_delta
0 2019-05-13 10:45:57 2019-05-13 10:45:57   00:00:00
1 2019-05-13 14:22:22 2019-05-13 10:45:57   03:36:25
2 2019-05-13 14:32:22 2019-05-13 14:22:22   00:10:00
3 2019-05-14 03:58:27 2019-05-13 14:32:22   13:26:05
4 2019-05-14 04:08:27 2019-05-14 03:58:27   00:10:00
5 2019-05-14 04:28:27 2019-05-14 04:08:27   00:20:00
```

My goal is to filter it by 'time_delta' column's value in the efficient way as possible.

```py
sec = 500
df = df[(d_df['time_delta']>(pd.Timedelta(sec, unit='s'))) | ((df['time_delta']==pd.Timedelta(0, unit='s')))]
```

it's works better than for loop but it still slow.
any suggestion?

Comment: time_delta just looks like an integer column.

Comment: @cs95 - i have update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "time_delta" is a column of `timedelta` type, then you can extract the total seconds as an integer (or float) and compare:

```
delta = df['time_delta'].dt.total_seconds()
df[(delta == 0) | (delta > sec)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
mask = (df['Time_delta'].dt
          .seconds
          .between(0,sec,
                   inclusive=False)
       )

df = df[mask]
```